XAML .NET MAUI. Binding Image Source в зависимости от темы устройства
Есть CollectionView который выводит массив однотипных блоков на разметку.
При изменение темы устройства необходимо изменять Image Source.
<Image x:Name="left_icon" Grid.Column="0" Source="{AppThemeBinding Light={Binding IconPrimaryDark}, Dark={Binding IconPrimary}}" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" />

Если вручную написать название файла изображения, то работает.
<Image x:Name="right_icon" Grid.Column="2" Source="{AppThemeBinding Light=right_arrow_primary_dark.svg, Dark=right_arrow_primary.svg}" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" />

XAML:
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding UserProfileMenuValuesList}" SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding NavigateToPageCommand}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUserProfileMenu}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Span="1" Orientation="Vertical" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BackgroundColor="Transparent" Stroke="{StaticResource PrimaryDark}" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="5" Padding="5">
                <Border.StrokeShape >
                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="15" />
                </Border.StrokeShape>

                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryDark}" />
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryDark}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="left_icon" Property="Image.Source" Value="{Binding IconPrimary}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="text_label" Property="Span.TextColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="right_icon" Property="Image.Source" Value="right_arrow_primary.svg" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto" ColumnSpacing="5">
                    <Image x:Name="left_icon" Grid.Column="0" Source="{AppThemeBinding Light={Binding IconPrimaryDark}, Dark={Binding IconPrimary}}" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" />
                    <Label x:Name="text_label" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Text}" TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryDark}"
                           FontSize="20" FontFamily="MontserratBold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <Image x:Name="right_icon" Grid.Column="2" Source="{AppThemeBinding Light=right_arrow_primary_dark.svg, Dark=right_arrow_primary.svg}" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

C#:
public class UserProfileMenu
{
    [JsonPropertyName("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [JsonPropertyName("iconPrimaryDark")]
    public string IconPrimaryDark { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [JsonPropertyName("iconPrimary")]
    public string IconPrimary { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [JsonPropertyName("pageName")]
    public string PageName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}


Вообще в MAUI x:Bind используют, а не Binding.
